# Recently updated VS Code + PHP XDebug - Disable 'auto expand data' arrays/objects

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

A recent update (not sure which, I updated yesterday since cancelling updates since end last year) of Visual Studio Code changed behavior of PHP Debug from XDebug (or even with PHP Tools extension from DEVSENSE) now has this 'auto-expand-data' feature, where arrays and objects now shows their values inline of the array/object, which in the case of Magento 2 makes debugging extremely cumbersome now.

**I should have just not upgraded!!!**

- The VS Code would crash more often now when large objects are displayed, because it now **wants to auto-expand every single private variable for a Magento 2 object as well**
- Since the extended feature 'auto-expands' variable values, it is not really clear anymore which are private/protected/public values any more.

Which recent settings are added, and how do we disable this?

### Example

New:

```
> 0:array(2)
0:"price"
1:"ASC"
> 1:array(2)
0:"name"
1:"ASC"
> 2:array(2)
0:"attr1"
1:"ASC"
> 3:array(2)
0:"attr2"
1:"ASC"
> 4:array(2)
0:"attr3"
1:"ASC"
```

Old:

```
> 0:array(2)
> 1:array(2)
> 2:array(2)
> 3:array(2)
```

Clearly the 'old way' (before updating VS Code today) is more concise and easier to read, I am giving an array example, since Magento 2 object would just cause VS Code to crash (so can't show an exact example).

> **It's even worse for objects, viewing (while debugging) any Magento 2 object now spans 1000s of lines, and VS Code will crash almost everytime)**

I don't need this feature, and would rather just want to access and view values as I need them from functions/variables:

For instance, when I would get $this->getCollection() from terminal now, I would get 1000s of unneeded values (private things expanded).

In debug terminal

```
// First find out what Collection is
$this->getCollection()

// Now since Collection processed filters, I might want to investigate `getSelect`
$this->getCollection()->getSelect();

// Also investigate 'from'
$this->getSelect()->getPart('from');
```

#### How can I disable this feature?

### Additional information

**TonyG** mentioned this in the comments as well, which I forgot to mention (as I just gave information on *terminal command view*), but this also happens to me.

> The Watch area shows correct tree structure. It's the mouse-over on variables in code that is problematic.

VS Code version:

```
Version: 1.64.2 (system setup)
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:02:28.252Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

PHP Debug (Xdebug)  `v1.24.2`

```
Last updated 23/02/2022, 09:00:55
Identifier xdebug.php-debug
```

XDebug on Server: (Ubuntu 20.04)

```
Zend Engine v3.3.21, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Please add information about VS Code version (Menu Help / About / Copy) and maybe the extension version (PHP Debug) that you are using, so I can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I came here about the exact same new behavior. I'm running VSCode v1.64.2/Windows with Xdebug 3.0.4 over Local by Flywheel/WPEngine (for WordPress). The Watch area shows correct tree structure. It's the mouse-over on variables in code that is problematic. @CvRChameleon, thanks for opening this question with clear articulation of the issue. Note however that the tag 'magento' may be misleading as this is not application-specific.

Comment: removed the magento tag — and do suggest what @zobo asked. He is the author.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will remove magento tag.  I hope we get a solution. @zobo, thank you will do! Give me 10 minutes to get to my work laptop.

Comment: @zobo I have added version information right at the bottom for `PHP Debug`, `Xdebug` and `VS Code`. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @CvRChameleon thanks for the update. You mention the "hover". Indeed the functionality there has changed, and is not using "eval" anymore, but "property_get". I can't seem to reproduce the problem. It's best if you open a ticket here https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues and provide the debug info, attach some screenshots and sample code.

Comment: @zobo - If you're talking about the recent change to phpDebug.ts for setting variables, the getter code for 'const property' hasn't changed there. Anyway, I encountered this issue with an associative array with nested indexed arrays: top[key] = []; top[key][]='foo';. And/Or, indexed elements that are themselves associative arrays: top = []; top[] = ['key'=>'foo'];. CvRChameleon, please let us know if you are going to file an issue sometime soon. If not, I can do it and will try to verify the trigger code. HTH

Comment: At this point I'm thinking the xdebug tag can be removed too. I also think the visual-studio-code tag should be replaced with vscode-debugger, based on info from Derick and zobo, but I'm out of my area of expertise so maybe that can be re-evaluated after the issue is resolved.

Comment: @zobo I will create a new ticket on `vscode-php-debug` Github page as requested.  Note: The 'hover' part was from @TonyG, which I have also seen, but using the terminal more since the objects used in Magento 2 is huge.  (So **hover** and **checking variables** in terminal gives the same output.  @TonyG I will certainly change the tags if they are available, thanks!

Comment: @zobo, @TonyG, @Derick, I created a new topic on `vscode-php-debug`, with more information / screenshots at the end of the post.  https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-expand issue was related to an issue with PHP Debug.

This issue was related to PHP Debug `~v1.24.1 or v1.24.2`.  Thanks for @zobo for the quick assistance on resolving the issue, much appreciated!

Solution:

> Install his new update: VS Code extension PHP Debug `v1.24.3`

Comment: Verified. From my perspective, this issue is closed. Thanks to zobo and thanks also to derick for jumping in so quickly. CvRChameleon - I believe you can mark your own answer as the solution. Congrats - and thanks to You!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, and thanks for the things you mentioned that I forgot, to clarify the issue even further!